# Sumar objetos dentro de una lista y encontrar el que mas valor tenga a diferencia de los demas

Tags: python

Tengo una lista con sublistas de esta manera:
`[['bananas', 15], ['frutillas', 12], ['frutillas', 13], ['frutillas', 10],  ['bananas', 11], ['mango', 13], ['mango', 15], ['bananas', 11], ['bananas',  12], ['frutillas', 10]]`
Quisiera saber cual fruta es la que tiene mas stock, probe con este codigo:

```
lista = [['bananas', 15], ['frutillas', 12], ['frutillas', 13], ['frutillas', 10], 
         ['bananas', 11], ['mango', 13], ['mango', 15], ['bananas', 11], ['bananas', 
         12], ['frutillas', 10]]
lista2 = list()
lista3 = list()
lista4 = list()
for val in lista:
    if 'bananas' in val:
        lista2.append(val[1])
    if 'frutillas' in val:
        lista3.append(val[1])
    if 'mango' in val:
        lista4.append(val[1])
suma = sum(lista2)
suma2 = sum(lista3)
suma3 = sum(lista4)
if suma > suma2 and suma > suma3:
    print('Las bananas tienen mas stock', suma)
elif suma2 > suma and suma2 > suma3:
    print('Las frutillas tienen mas stock', suma2)
else:
    print('Los mangos tienen mas stock', suma3)
```

Este codigo funciona, pero es inmantenible ya que si hubieran mas datos deberia crear mas listas y a la vez mas condiciones if.
Alguna otra forma de hacerlo mas intuitivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas de resolver esto. Una propuesta puede ser con un diccionario. Si el producto no está en el mismo (`if`), se agrega junto con su cantidad inicial. Si el producto ya existe (`else`), entonces se le suma al valor actual.

```
data = {}
for producto, cant in lista:
    if producto not in data:
        data[producto] = cant
    else:
        data[producto] += cant

print(data) # {'bananas': 49, 'frutillas': 45, 'mango': 28}
```

Ahora para sacar el elemento que tiene el [máximo valor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280156/1545868) en el diccionario

```
elem_mayor = max(data, key=data.get)

print(f'Las {elem_mayor} tienen mas stock: {data[elem_mayor]}')
# Las bananas tienen mas stock: 49
```

---

[Explicacion del `for`]: El ciclo `for` recorre cada elemento de la lista y se lo asigna a la variable de la izquierda. Pero en este caso cada elemento es una sublista (`['bananas', 15]`, `['frutillas', 12]`, etc...) y a la izquierda ¡2 variables! (`producto` y `cant`)

Si en Python se asigna un iterable (listas, tuplas, etc) cuya cantidad de elementos sea exactamente igual a la cantidad de variables, automáticamente el iterable se desempaca y le asigna cada elemento respectivo a cada variable.

```
>>> a = [2, 5] # a vale [2, 5]
>>> a, b = [2, 5] # a vale 2, b vale 5 (se desempacó)
>>> a, b, c = [2, 5] # TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable
```

El ciclo `for` soporta desempacado, por eso en cada iteración, el toma una sublista, pero le asigna el nombre de la fruta a `producto` y la cantidad a `cant`

Comment: Me sirvio muchas gracias!
Me podrias explicar con mas detalle lo que hace el ciclo for?

Comment: @faraway97 el ciclo for se utiliza para recorrer elementos en este caso una lista, la cual tiene 2 elemtos **producto** y **cantidad**

Comment: @faraway97 listo, ya agregué una explicación